# Copy file from Remote Server using PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, copy, remote-server, pgadmin-4

I am trying to copy a file from my Office Remote server as CSV output on my local machine (windows). I cannot use the export/import dialog. It shows the following error

> Utility file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

The same command works fine for local server files meaning I have already edited the binary path in the Configuration setting.

The COPY command gives the following error

> ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file SQL state: 42602

\Copy doesn't work either.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: You have to correct the binary path in the "Preferences" dialog to where you installed the PostgreSQL client binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

You can generate the CSV file like this:

copy(select * from schema.table) TO '/tmp/file.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER '|';

Comment: Thanks. It runs successfully. But where is this tmp folder located? I cannot use 'C:/Pg/file.csv'

Comment: In this case I recorded the file in OS linux, but if you are using windows just change the name of the directory.